# phpでmysqlにデータを保存しているデータをid毎に静的フアィルhtmlに生成して書き出したいです

Tags: php, mysql

phpでmysqlデータベースに
test_id, test_title, test_contents, test_date.test_imageのデータを保存しています。このデータのid毎に静的htmlに生成して書き出したいです。WordPressやMovable Typeの静的ファイルの書き出すとかに似ているイメージです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

例えば：上記添付した画像(CMS.png)の書き出すボタンを押すと添付した画像(database.png)から、/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/のディレクトリーの下に静的htmlファイにて生成して書き出したいです
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/1.html
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/2.html

1.htmlと2.htmlにはデータベースに保存されているtest_id, test_title, test_contents, test_date.test_imageのデータ内容がそれぞれのhtmlに全部表示されるようにしたいです

これはphpや何かをして書き出すことは可能でしょうか？　ご教授お願い致します。

---

@D.T さん
sync.phpファイルは下記です。

```
<?php
   //require_once("db.php");
   //  取得するIDをURLパラメータから取得
    if (!isset($_GET['test_id'])) {
       echo '{$test_id} param not found. please set param [id] to url params.';
    return;
}
$test_id = $_GET['test_id'];

//  データベースに接続
//$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "product");
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if ($db->connect_error) {
    echo 'database connect failed.';
    return;
}
if ($db->set_charset('utf8') === false) {
    echo 'database connect failed. can not using utf-8.';
    return;
}

//  データ取得とhtmlに変換
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>{$id} </title></head><body>";
//データベース名前はproductです, 今回の想定はいくつからのテーブルあって、その中のtestテーブルです
$result = $db->query("select * from test where test_id = {$test_id};");    //  本当はidのエスケープを考慮しないといけない　でもselectなのでべつにこのままでも危険な事にはならない。
$rows = array();
for ($i=0; ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) != null; $i++) {    //  一応一致した全行出力する
    if ($i > 0) {
    $html .= '<br />';
}
    $html .= 'test_id = ' . $row['test_id'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_title = ' . $row['test_title'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_contents = ' . $row['test_contents'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_date = ' . $row['test_date'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_image = ' . $row['test_image'];
}
$html .= "</body></html>";

//  ファイルに書き出し
if (file_put_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/{$test_id}.html", $html) === false) {
    echo 'write to file failed.';
} else {
    echo 'write to file succeed.';
}
```

---

@D.Tさんこちらが全ファイルです。
sync.phpとadmin.phpとdb.phpは同じディレクトリ下にあります。

sync.phpこちらは@D.Tさんのファイル

```
//  取得するIDを取得
if (!isset($_GET['test_id']) && !isset($_POST['test_id'])) {
    print '[test_id] param not found. please set param [test_id] to url params or post values.';
    return;
}
$id = isset($_GET['test_id'])? $_GET['test_id']:$_POST['test_id'];

//  データベースに接続
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
//$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "product");//ここだけを自分の環境に合わせてみました。
if ($db->connect_error) {
    print 'database connect failed.';
    return;
}
if ($db->set_charset('utf8') === false) {
    print 'database connect failed. can not using utf-8.';
    return;
}

//  データ取得とhtmlに変換
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\" /><title>{$id}  </title></head><body>";
$result = $db->query("select * from test where test_id = {$id};");    //  本当 はidのエスケープを考慮しないといけない　でもselectなのでべつにこのままでも危険な事にはならない。
for ($i=0; ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) != null; $i++) {    //  一応一致した全行出力する
    if ($i > 0) {
        $html .= '<br />';
    }
    $html .= 'test_id = ' . $row['test_id'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_title = ' . $row['test_title'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_contents = ' . $row['test_contents'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_date = ' . $row['test_date'] . ', ';
    $html .= 'test_image = ' . $row['test_image'];
}
 $html .= "</body></html>";

 //  ファイルに書き出し
if (file_put_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/{$id}.html", $html) === false) {
    print 'write to file failed.';
 } else {
     print 'write to file succeed.';
?>
```

admin.php

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test_id DESC";
    $select = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
        $test_id =$row['test_id'];
        $test_title = $row['test_title'];
        $test_contents =$row['test_contents'];
        $test_date =$row['test_date'];
        $test_image =$row['test_image'];
        echo "<tr>";
?>
<?php 
        echo "<td>$test_id</td>";
        echo "<td>$test_title</td>";
        echo "<td>$test_contents</td>";
        echo "<td>$test_date</td>";
        echo "<td>$test_image</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=''>編集</td>";
        echo "<td><a rel=''>削除</td>";
        echo "<td><form action='sync.php' method='post'><div class='form-group'>
                <input type='hidden' name='test_id' value='".$test_id."'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn' name='submit' value='書き出す'>
               </div></form></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

}

db.php

```
<?php
    $db['db_host'] = "localhost";
    $db['db_user'] = "root";
    $db['db_pass'] = "root";
    $db['db_name'] = "product";

    foreach($db as $key => $value){
        define(strtoupper($key), $value);

   }
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
       mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
  ?>
```

Comment: 普通は、書きだすというより、
phpにアクセスしたらhtmlに変換して出力するのですが、あくまでファイルとして書き出したいのでしょうか？

普通は
1.html　に　アクセスしたら、　実際は　1.html　というファイルは実際になく、phpに処理が流れてhtmlを毎回生成して出力するのが一般的です。

Comment: @D.T 
test環境はご指摘通りですが例えば、テスト環境から本番環境データを同期する時に静的ファイルのみを置きたいです。ですので、実際に静的ファイルhtmlを生成して書き出さないと行けないと思っています。

Comment: @D.T SOは掲示板ではないので、コメントや回答を使ってディスカッションするのは止めましょう。質問に情報不足があるなら質問を編集して追記するように促してください。

Comment: @2015 SOは掲示板ではないので、コメントや回答を使ってディスカッションするのは止めましょう。質問への追加情報は質問を編集することで追記してください。追加の疑問など質問への回答でないことを「回答」として投稿しないでください。

Comment: 他の方もコメントされているように、回答欄は掲示板のようなやりとりには不向きです。時系列で投稿が表示されるわけではないので、ご自身のソースコードを回答欄に投稿すると、回答者の方にも分かりにくくなります。追加情報は質問を編集することで追記していただけるとうれしいです。（現時点までに回答として投稿されていた補足情報は、モデレーター権限で質問への編集に変換しました。）

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/30629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お待たせしました
sync.phpの中身を下にまるまる書き換えて下さい。
また、今回はエスケープを行うなどしてそのまま実用できるようにしました。

```
<?php
//  取得するIDを取得（GET or POST name is test_id type:number）
if (!isset($_GET['test_id']) && !isset($_POST['test_id'])) {
    print '[test_id] param not found. please set [test_id] param to url params or post values.';
    return;
}
$id = isset($_GET['test_id'])? $_GET['test_id']:$_POST['test_id'];

//  パラメータが10進数の数値かチェック
if (!ctype_digit($id) || strlen($id)==0) {
    print '[test_id] is invalid param type. need number.';
    return;
}

//  データベースに接続（現存のコードを利用）
require_once('db.php');

//  データベースからデータ取得
$result = mysqli_query($db, "select * from test where test_id={$id} order by test_id desc;");

//  データ取得と同時にhtmlに変換
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\" /><title>{$id}</title></head><body><table><tbody>";
$found = false;
for ($i=0; ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != null; $i++) {   //  一致したレコード分だけ繰り返す
    $found = true;

    //  ヘッダの出力
    if ($i == 0) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            $html .= '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '</th>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }

    //  値の出力
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $value)) . '</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
if (!$found) {
    $html .= '<tr><td>１つも一致するデータはありません。</td></tr>';
}
$html .= "</tbody></table></body></html>";

//  ファイルに書き出し
if (file_put_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/{$id}.html", $html) === false) {
    print 'write to file failed.';
} else {
    print $html;
}
```

?>

Comment: @D.Tさん、
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/に書き出せませんでした。admin.phpの書き出すボタンを押してもsync.phpが実行されてない気がしました。エラーなど何も出ませんから。

Comment: 直接sync.phpにアクセスしたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 流石にこれで動かないのであれば、おかしいですね…
なんにも出ないならphpのエラーだと思いますが、エラーはないですね…
phpのバージョンも極端に古くなければ問題ないかと。
syncとdbとadminは同じディレクトリで、adminページはURLの最後がadmin.phpで終わっているんですよね？

以下の２点のチェックをお願いします。
・直接sync.phpにアクセスしたらどうなるか。
・sync.phpをsync.txtに書き換えて直接アクセスしたらどうなるか

Comment: 流石に書き出すボタンを押したら新しいページが開かれますよね？
真っ白でもいいので。
管理画面から切り替わらないならそれはadmin.phpの単純なミスでしょうが…

Comment: 上記２点を確認してもだめならアクセス権限のせいかもしれないですね。
今はftpでアップロードしていますか？
sync.phpを右クリックとかのメニューからアクセス権限を変えられると思います。
sync.phpのアクセス権限をadmin.phpとかと同じにしてみてください。
わからなければ「755　rwxr-xr-x」にどちらか片方設定できるところがあると思うので。

Comment: @D.Tさん
ありがとうございます、最初の目的html書き出しはできました。ですがデータベースにidが1,2,があって、しかし、1.htmlしか書き出せなくて、それ以外idの書き出すボタンを押すと、何も反応がないです。ボタンのURLを見るとformのactionがないです。その画像を添付します。admin.phpの問題ですかね!?

Comment: それも変な話ですね…
admin.phpを見たところ
ループで同じコードを出力しているのでidが変わると動かないということはないはずですが…

Comment: なぜですかね！！権限とか大丈夫ですし、全部777にしています

Comment: ごちゃごちゃなってわかりづらいので
これをチェックしたほうがいいかと思います。

Answer (score -2):

ごちゃごちゃなりましたが、これは
htmlの書き出しはできたけど、他のIDだとできないものがあるにたいしての回答です。

```
echo "<td><form action='sync.php' method='post'><div class='form-group'>
            <input type='hidden' name='test_id' value='".$test_id."'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn' name='submit' value='書き出す'>
           </div></form></td>";
```

試しに↓に書き換えてください。

```
echo "<td><form action='sync.php' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='test_id' value='{$test_id}'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn' name='submit' value='書き出す'>
           </form></td>";
```

やっぱりこっちに書き換えて下さい
inputを閉じていないのが原因…！？？？

```
echo "<td><form action='sync.php' method='post'><div class='form-group'>
            <input type='hidden' name='test_id' value='{$test_id}' />
            <input type='submit' class='btn' name='submit' value='書き出す' />
           </div></form></td>";
```

Comment: 追記しました
３番目を試してみてだめなら２番目を試して下さい

Comment: @D.Tさん
3番と2番を使っても同じ1.htmlしか書き出せませんでした

Comment: @D.Tさん
idに3,4,5,6,に追加してみたら,一番最新の6が書き出せませんでした、それ以外は書き出せました。

Comment: それでは１番目を丸まるこれに書き換えて下さい。
「「「print "<td><button class=\"btn\" onclick=\"window.open('sync.php?test_id={$test_id}', '_blank');\">書き出す</button></td>";」」」

Comment: @D.Tさん
おかげさまで、できました。非常に勉強になりました。ありがとうごいます！！心から感謝です

Comment: 良かったです！レイアウトは崩れていませんか？（divを抜いちゃったのですがdivは入れててもいいかもしれませんね）

あと、さっき送ったの多少好ましく無いです↓に書き換えてください（divはお任せします）
「「「print "<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" onclick=\"window.open('sync.php?test_id={$test_id}', '_blank');\">書き出す</button></td>";」」」

Comment: 最後に↑をお願いします。
じゃあ頑張ったのでベストアンサーのチェックをおねがいしますね(笑)

Comment: はい、少し崩れていました。
あと、一点質問ですが$html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp"><head>
<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html\; charset=\"utf-8\" />
<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"../images/favicon.ico\">
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../style/style.min.css\" /> 
<link href=\"../css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>{$special_id}</title></head><body><table><tbody>";
などを入れるとエラーが出ます、

Comment: phpから見て　""　の中の文字に　"　を使うなら中で使うものを　\"　としないといけないです。

phpから見て　''　の中の文字に　'　を使うなら中で使うものを　\'　としないといけないです。

様子するに、とりあえず　"　を　\"　に置き換えてください。
html上の　"　だけです。
<html lang="jp">　なら　<html lang=\"jp\">

Comment: これはもっといい方法があるのですが…
ちょっと説明しきれないです…

Comment: ありがとうございます。ベストアンサーのチェックしました。
チェックの入れた方あっていますよね！！笑　あまり使ったことがなくて

Comment: アンサーありがとうございます
↑の件についてもちょっとだけ解答します
少しお待ちを…

Comment: 一番手っ取り早いのは、私のコード上のphpからみた「'」を「"」に全て置き換えて、
2015さんの改造したいようにhtmlでは「"」のかわりに「'」を使うようにして下さい。

【参考１ http://www.24w.jp/study_contents.php?bid=php&iid=php&sid=string&cid=006】


【参考２ http://www.phpbook.jp/tutorial/string/index4.html】

Comment: @D.Tさん
ありがとうございます